# PayPal Adaptive Payment Checkout Hide Receiver Email?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm pretty new to using the PayPal Adaptive Payments API where we have two receivers for any payment.  In the checkout process the email address of the receivers are displayed on the receipt page as well as the email invoice.  Is there any way to toggle this off so only the name is shown, not the email addy?  I have not been able to find anything in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from talking with PayPal, it is their policy to display all users involved with a transaction. As far as I know there is no toggle; the user's email is only shown if their name or business name is not available.
Also, I believe that the email is shown in the confirmation email regardless.